# Show that $[2,\infty)$ is also uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> **Question:**
>
> Assume $A$ is the only uncountable set that we currently know of, where
>   $A= \{ x\in (0,1): x \text{ is a decimal fraction consisting only of combinations of 0 and 1} \}$
>
> From this fact, show that $[2,\infty)$ is uncountable.

How do I go about showing this? Any hints will be much appreciated :)

Comment: I believe you mean “$ x $ has a decimal *expansion* consisting only of $ 0 $’s and $ 1 $’s.” Hence,
$$
  A
= \left\{
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{10^{n}} ~ \middle| ~
  (a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}
  \setminus (0)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}
  \right\}.
$$

Comment: The wording with "the only" is weird, as the definition of $A$ seems unique.

Comment: What is meant by that, is that we must assume A is the only uncountable set "that we know of"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**HINT:** Find an injection from $A$ into $[2,\infty)$. And remember that a superset of an uncountable set is uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

Let $B= \left \{ x \in  \left (2 ,+\infty \right ] : x = y + 2, y \in A \right \} $, show that $|A| = |B|$ (hint: there is a biyective function), add that $B \subseteq \left(2,3 \right)\subseteq\left(2,+\infty\right]$ and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

try looking at the elements of $A$ as binary numbers (numbers in base $2$). $0 \notin A$ so the smallest possible value of $A$ is $0.000...01$ and if you look at the fraction part only, that number is $2$ in decimal base.

Do you agree that we can represent any number from $2$ to infinity using only the fraction part of $x \in A$?

Edit: I know it's not formal, we can't really say that $A$ has a minimal value, but the idea is correct. it's a hint, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Technical Warning: You would want to take a unique representation for each $x$.

Outline: Draw the graph of a bijective function (e.g. a tangentesque one) to show that $]0,1[=]2,\infty[$. Then argue that adding a point does not change the cardinality provided that the set is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

From the question we assume $A$ is not countable, thus $\mbox{card } A > \mbox{card } \mathbb{N}$.
We can map $A$ bijectively to $(0,1)$ by interpreting the digits $d_k$ of $x = (0.d_1 d_2 \cdots)_{10}\in A$ as choice of the left or right interval in a sequence of nested intervals of length $1/2^k$ of $(0,1)$ which enclose $y = (0.d_1 d_2 \cdots)_2$.

Using $f(x) = 2/x$ we can map $[2,\infty)$ to $(0,1]$ and back.
We have $(0,1) \subset (0,1]$, so $\mbox{card }(0,1) \le \mbox{card }(0,1]$.
Further we can map $(0,1]$ bijectively to $(0, 1/2] \subset (0,1)$ via
$g(x) = x/2$, so $\mbox{card }(0,1] \le \mbox{card }(0,1)$, therefore
$\mbox{card }[2,\infty) = \mbox{card }(0,1] = \mbox{card }(0,1) =\mbox{card } A$. Then as $A$ is not countable, so $[2,\infty)$ is not countable.